# No such file or directory in spark cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I am writing a spark-streaming application using pyspark which basically process the data.

Inshort packaging overview:
This application contains several modules and some config files which are non .py files **(ex:.yaml or .json)**.

I am packaging this entire application in package.zip file and submitting this package.zip to spark.

Now the problem is when i issue the spark-submit command in yarn cluster mode. I get IOError. Below is stacktrace

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main/main.py", line 10, in <module>
     import logger.logger
   File "package.zip/logger/logger.py", line 36, in get_logger
   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'logger/config.yaml'
```

Spark-Command :
**spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --py-files package.zip main/main.py**

But when I am submitting job in yarn-client mode the application works as expected.

My understanding:

1. When I submit the job in client mode the **spark driver** runs in same machine where I have issued the command. And the package is distributed across all nodes.
2. And when I issue the command in cluster mode the both **spark driver** and **application master** runs in single node(which is not client who submitted code.) and still package is distribute to all nodes in cluster.

In both the cases package.zip is available to all nodes then why is that only py files are getting loaded and non py files are failed to load in cluster mode.

Can any one please help me to understand the situation here and resolve the problem?

**Updated--**

**Observations**

In **Client Mode** The zipped package is unzipped in the path where driver script is running.
Where as in **Cluster Mode** the zip package shared across all node but not unzipped. 
Here do I need to unzip package in all nodes ?
**Is there any way to tell spark to unzip package in worker node?**

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your extra files with `--files` option.

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-submit.html

Comment: Though the link might solve the issue its better to provide the details out here rather than just a link.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh is right, because, that link does not exist anymore!

Comment: Link does not exist anymore.